Expo android problem of making android build unknown error
I was trying to make an android build for my app but this error occurs do you guys have any solution for it ? Can you check if there's any deprecated dependency that is not compatible with the 50 and 51 expo version ?
The error:
✖ Build failed
 Android build failed:
Gradle build failed with unknown error. See logs for the "Run gradlew" phase for more information.
I expected the app to be built but I have no clue I saw the log and it says
Running 'gradlew :app:bundleRelease' in /home/expo/workingdir/build/aqwa_cars_mobile/android
Downloading https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-8.6-all.zip
10%.
20%.
30%.
40%
50%.
60%.
70%.
80%.
90%.
100%
Welcome to Gradle 8.6!
Here are the highlights of this release:

Configurable encryption key for configuration cache
Build init improvements
Build authoring improvements
For more details see https://docs.gradle.org/8.6/release-notes.html
To honour the JVM settings for this build a single-use Daemon process will be forked. For more on this, please refer to https://docs.gradle.org/8.6/userguide/gradle_daemon.html#sec:disabling_the_daemon in the Gradle documentation.
Daemon will be stopped at the end of the build
Path for java installation '/usr/lib/jvm/openjdk-17' (Common Linux Locations) does not contain a java executable


Task :gradle-plugin:pluginDescriptors
Task :gradle-plugin:processResources
Task :gradle-plugin:compileKotlin
Task :gradle-plugin:compileJava NO-SOURCE
Task :gradle-plugin:classes
Task :gradle-plugin:jar
Task :gradle-plugin:inspectClassesForKotlinIC
Configure project :expo-av
Checking the license for package NDK (Side by side) 26.1.10909125 in /home/expo/Android/Sdk/licenses
License for package NDK (Side by side) 26.1.10909125 accepted.
Preparing "Install NDK (Side by side) 26.1.10909125 v.26.1.10909125".
"Install NDK (Side by side) 26.1.10909125 v.26.1.10909125" ready.
Installing NDK (Side by side) 26.1.10909125 in /home/expo/Android/Sdk/ndk/26.1.10909125
"Install NDK (Side by side) 26.1.10909125 v.26.1.10909125" complete.
"Install NDK (Side by side) 26.1.10909125 v.26.1.10909125" finished.
FAILURE: Build completed with 2 failures.
1: Task failed with an exception.



Where:
Build file '/home/expo/workingdir/build/aqwa_cars_mobile/node_modules/expo-file-system/android/build.gradle' line: 10
What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating project ':expo-file-system'.


Could not find method useDefaultAndroidSdkVersions() for arguments [] on project ':expo-file-system' of type org.gradle.api.Project.


Try:


Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
Run with --scan to get full insights.
Get more help at https://help.gradle.org.
==============================================================================
2: Task failed with an exception.



Where:
Script '/home/expo/workingdir/build/aqwa_cars_mobile/node_modules/expo-modules-core/android/ExpoModulesCorePlugin.gradle' line: 65
What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring project ':expo'.


Could not get unknown property 'release' for SoftwareComponent container of type org.gradle.api.internal.component.DefaultSoftwareComponentContainer.


Try:


Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
Run with --scan to get full insights.
Get more help at https://help.gradle.org.
==============================================================================
BUILD FAILED in 2m 22s
5 actionable tasks: 5 executed
Error: Gradle build failed with unknown error. See logs for the "Run gradlew" phase for more information.

